# Insert a date in MySQL only if it is valid

Tags: mysql, sql, string, date

I have a table with date values stored as strings, like `'2012-01-15'`. Some of them are invalid, like `'2012-04-31'`. I would like to insert the valid dates into a `DATE` type column in another table, and default the day to 1 if it is too large for the month.

`DAYNAME` seems to be the only function in MySQL that will check whether a date is valid. However, it issues a warning for an invalid date (in addition to returning `NULL`), which upgrades to an error in an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement.

So I'd like to do something like

```sql
INSERT INTO date_tbl (date_value)
SELECT IF(DAYNAME(date_string) IS NOT NULL, date_string, CONCAT(LEFT(date_string, 8), '1')
FROM date_string_table;
```

This fails with `Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '2010-04-31'` even though I am not actually inserting invalid data.

The problem with using `INSERT IGNORE` is running the risk of actually inserting invalid data, which I would really like to avoid.

---

EDIT Oct 5:

This problem can be reproduced without creating the intermediate table simply as

```sql
CREATE TABLE date_tbl (
    date_val DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO date_tbl (date_val)
SELECT IF(DAYNAME('2012-04-31') IS NOT NULL, '2012-04-31', NULL);
```

I would like the above `INSERT` to insert NULL for that invalid date, instead of failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare days of the proper date and last day for that month with `LAST_DAY` and `STR_TO_DATE`.

So your query would be:

```
INSERT INTO date_tbl (date_val)
SELECT IF(DAY(STR_TO_DATE('2012-02-30','%Y-%m-%d')) > DAY(LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE('2012-02-30','%Y-%m-%d'))), NULL,'2012-02-30');
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6yb8fQRLqonix6HmSsg2eU/3)

Answer (score -2):

A workaround is to use `INSERT IGNORE` and then validate after the fact:

```sql
SELECT date_value
FROM date_tbl
WHERE DAYNAME(date_value) IS NULL;
```

Should return zero rows.